# comment posting not functioning in django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, rest

so, im using django rest framework on the backend and angular.js for the frontend.

all the forms including login and post form work just fine except the comment box.

I realize im getting 400 error if i try to type something, that says "This filed may not be blank"

the comment form is located inside the angular js template called 'post.html' but

i've tried putting the form both inside the template and outside the template, just in case the django rest framework cannot get into the angular js template.

but both is throwing the same error right now it seems.

here is the live site : http://192.241.153.25:8000/#/post/test7

can anyone help me out on this? thanks.

if you need any more source to solve the problem you may request what you need.

index.html's jquery code

```
  $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '/api/comments/create/',
    data:$('#post_form').serialize(),
    error: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      alert('Not authorized.');  // Or something in a message DIV
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $('.login_bar').html(response)
      $('.login_bar').html(response)
      $('#logout_form').toggleClass(show)
    // do something with response
 }
});

});
```

post.html

```
    <div class="post_article_container">
    <div class="post_top_navigation"></div>
    <a class="previous_button" href="#/posts" onclick="jQuery('.post_container').addClass('animate_out')">



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="post_container animate_in">

        <div class="post_title_bar">
      <div id="ios-arrow-left" title="Go Back"></div></a>
        <h6 class="post_date">{{post.publish}}</h6>
    </div>

<div class="post_content_wrapper">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div>
          <div style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">{{post.content}}<br>
                    <img src="{{ post.image }}"></div>

                    <form id="comment_form" method="post" action="">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                    <textarea name="content" placeholder="content"></textarea>
                      <button class="ladda-button button-primary login_button" ng-click="vm.submit()"/><span class="ladda-label">submit</span></button>
                    </form>

          <div ng-if="post.comments.length">
            <strong>Comments:</strong>
              <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
                {{comment.content}}<br> {{comment.timestamp}}
              </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.js

```
    (function() {
  angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
.controller('FilesListCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {//this one controller is new

    $scope.images = [];
    $scope.next_page = null;
    var in_progress = true;

    $scope.loadImages = function() {
    //alert(in_progress);
            if (in_progress){
            var url = '/api/posts/';//api url
            if ($scope.next_page) {
                url = $scope.next_page;
            }
            $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data.results);//according to api
                $scope.next_page = data.next;//acccording to api

                if ( ( $scope.next_page == null ) || (!$scope.next_page) ) {
                    in_progress = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };



    $scope.loadImages();
}])
.directive('whenScrolled', function($document) {//another directive
        return function(scope, elm, attr) {
            var raw = elm[0];

             $document.bind('scroll', function() {
                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
                }
            });
        };
    })
    .config(function($resourceProvider, $routeProvider) {
      // Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
      $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          template: '<posts></posts>'
        })
        .when('/posts', {
          template: '<posts></posts>'
        })
        .when('/post/:postId', {
          template: '<post></post>'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
  angular.module('app')
    .constant('API_URL', '/api/posts/');
  angular.module('app')
    .factory('Posts', function($resource, API_URL) {
      return $resource(API_URL, {format: 'json'}, {
        queryPosts: {
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: false
        },
        getPostInfo: {
          url: API_URL + ':postId/',
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: false,
          params: {
            postId: '@postId',
            format: 'json'
          }
        }
      });
    });
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('post', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/static/post.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $routeParams, Posts) {
          $scope.post = null;

          function clean(id) {
        return id.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-");
      }

      function _initialize() {
   Posts.getPostInfo({
     postId: clean($routeParams.postId)
   })
              .$promise
                .then(function(result) {
                  $scope.post = result;
                  console.log(result)
                });
          }
          _initialize();
        }
      };
    });
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('posts', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/static/posts.html',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, Posts) {
          $scope.posts = [];
          function _initialize() {
            Posts.queryPosts().$promise.then(function(result) {
              $scope.posts = result.results;
            });
          }
          _initialize();
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

Comment: and comments API : http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/comments/create/

Comment: Might need your views.py code, especially post method implementation

Comment: @be_good_do_good here is the comment api's views.py
https://dpaste.de/UGuJ let me know if you need the serializers.py as well.